# An Apache Storm bolt receive multiple input tuples from different spout/bolt

Tags: java, apache-storm

Is it possible for a bolt receive multiple input tuples from different spout/bolt?
For instance, Bolt C receive input tuples from Spout A and input tuples from Bolt B to be processed. How should I implement it? I mean writing the Java code for Bolt C and also its topology.

Comment: What do you mean? I'm new here, so I don't exactly know what you mean.

Comment: You should see a tick on the left of the each answer, if you think one of the answers are true, then click that tick. It tells others that you accepted the answer as a solution to your problem. You can also upvote nice questions and answers, telling they are worth reading.

Comment: For example someone just upvoted your question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tutorial answers your question.

https://storm.apache.org/documentation/Tutorial.html

Here is the code for your goal(C/P from tutorial):

```
builder.setBolt("exclaim2", new ExclamationBolt(), 5)
            .shuffleGrouping("words")
            .shuffleGrouping("exclaim1");
```

`exclaim2` will accept tuples from both `words` and `exclaim1`, both using shuffle grouping.

Comment: This was helpful. It would be nice to know if chaining can be done dynamically (via a loop) also. I have a variable number of bolts that would be generated via a loop and I want all of them to send their emitted Tuples to a single bolt. `for(int i=0;i<10;++i) {builder.setBolt("a",new someBolt(),5).shuffleGrouping("Bolt"+i);}`. Each iteration of the loop should chain one more Bolt. Is it possible in any way?

Answer (score 2):

Yes Possible. Only thing to take care is it should follow DAG structure.
In your case, below is the flow.
1. Spout reads the data and sends to bolt C
2. Same Spout reads the data and sends to bolt B
3. Bolt B filters some data and forwards to Bolt C